# Yocto - Full implementation of "ip address" command

Tags: ip, yocto, busybox

I have problem with yocto implementation of `ip` command. It seems to be significantly reduced in BusyBox implementation. I'm trying to install python software, that calls `ip -json -det address`. On standard Linux instalation this works as fine and returns valid json as response, but not in Yocto. What is the correct way to compile full version of `ip` to my Yocto image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a config fragment for busybox, for example called `disable_network.cfg` (the `.cfg` part is important). Its content should be 1 line: `# CONFIG_IP is not set`. Add this file to the `SRC_URI` variable using a bbappend. This should disable busybox's ip command.
2. Then add `iproute2` package to your image (`IMAGE_INSTALL`), this installs the full version of ip command.